# How to undo textbf?

Tags: bold

For reference, please consider the following code, which "does not lie", i.e., it's true that only words word1 and word2 appear bold, and word3 appears non-bold.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textbf{word1} appears bold. \textnormal{\textbf{word2}} appears bold.
\textbf{\textnormal{word3}} appears normal.
\end{document}
```

Now my question: If I want to undo the effects of \textbf, how do I do that? I found multiple posts, wrongly claiming that this can be achieved by putting \textnormal in front of it, but the code above proves that this is wrong. So how do I do that?

To provide a motivating example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\MyDef}{\textbf{usually bold}}
Here is some text, which is \MyDef.
However, the text "\UndoBold{\MyDef}" sometimes should also appear not in bold.
\end{document}
```

So, what is the command \UndoBold? As said, I was only finding \textnormal, but clearly that's not true as proved by my minimal example above.

Comment: `\textbf\textbf{word2}` does not appear bold

Comment: there is no command which works as you want it, you would have to define a new command which locally maps \bfdefault to m.

Comment: "but the code above proves that this is wrong. " not really, you are just mis-reading the processing order. `textnormal undoes bold` means `\textbf{\textnormal{word3}} appears normal.`

Comment: @JamesT oh sorry you are right, it actually manages to avoid flagging an error by an unintented series of accidental expansions. it has no valid reason for doing anything though, it is  `\textbf{\textbf}{word}` the inner  `\textbf` has no argument but actually picks up `\check@icr ` the italic correction check of the outer one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the explanation, that is pretty interesting, I need to learn more. I am assuming then that is more of a bug then an intended effect then, I won't rely on it from now if I ever needed it and don't recommend the OP use it!

Comment: @JamesT  there are lots of similar things that are not trapped, we just didn't have the speed or memory available to add more checks in 1990s

Comment: Thanks everybody! I created a 'work-around answer' based on all your feedback. Regarding the first reply that \textbf\textbf{word2} does indeed print it non-bold: interesting! :) But this doesn't help since in my case also \textbf\MyDef seems to be treated just like \textbf{\MyDef}, so it remains bold. I can live with the workaround, though it's still a bit less elegant than what I was looking for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: The straight forward soultion is ... deleting \textbf + { + }.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because final comments indicate "solved by user".

Comment: @José: the question was actually not answered in the comments. Well, unless you define 'solved' as "this problem can't be solved", then yes. :) (Hence my work-around-solution since the respective command sadly doesn't seem to exist.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments to my question I assume there doesn't seem to be a command which I can put around the textbf to undo its effect. So instead I went with a conditional, which should do the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\MyText}{usually bold}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyDef}{o}{%
    % cases depend on whether any optional argument is used
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\textbf{\MyText}}{\MyText}%
}

Here is some text, which is \MyDef.
However, the text "\MyDef[nonBold]" sometimes should also appear not in bold
(which is the case here!).

\end{document}
```

Here, the text also the text does not lie, meaning that indeed the first occurrence of "usually bold" is bold, whereas the second is not.